# How do I handle a DBNull DateTime field coming from the SQL Server?

Tags: c#, datetime, null, dbnull

I am getting this error when I retrieve a row with a null DataTime field:

> 'srRow.Closed_Date' threw an exception of type 'System.Data.StrongTypingException'

How do I properly handle these?

Comment: How are you pulling down the information? Is it in a data table or a strong typed object?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can check for a null value in that column before retrieving the value.

```
if (!srRow.IsClosed_DateNull())
{
  myDate = srRow.Closed_Date;
}
```

Comment: +1 Good answer - yours should be the accepted answer, not the IsNull answer

Answer (score 1):

There's a reference [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms242030(VS.80).aspx).

or possibly, can you modify your query to ensure the results are not null by using the IsNull operator?

```
Select (IsNull, SomeDateField, GetDate())
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using .NET, there are [SqlTypes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqltypes.aspx) that can be used in a situation like this.